# Fat rails app to log data into aws kinesis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have this fat Rails app I run on a number of ec2 instances over a nfs share. Because of this the log files get clogged and I'd like to be able to view exceptions or errors and several other things as they happen.

Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: For exception notification, you might want to try airbrake: https://airbrake.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool for this kind of work is to use a log management service, which provides a real-time interface for monitoring and doesn't require setting up all the infrastructure for AWS Kinesis.

There are some based on `syslogd` and have a really good integration with Rails.

Be sure to check out:

- Papertrail ([papertrailapp.com](http://papertrailapp.com))
- Loggly ([www.loggly.com](http://www.loggly.com))
- Splunk ([www.splunk.com](http://www.splunk.com) - on-premise)

Comment: Well, I know these... would prefer a non-commercial solution as I'm used to play with things, besides, our thing generates about 5 gigs of traffic a day, or 10 if we log all that we want logged, so it will quickly become inefficient in terms of costs compared to a pure AWS based solution where eventually we'll only pay for storage.

Comment: I see, maybe [fluentd](http://fluentd.org/) is what you're looking for, it has a Kinesis plugin. I don't see any other solution which doesn't involve writing your own producer to tail these log files using the Kinesis API.